# Unexpected 'a' json o/p while running in postman

Tags: php, json

```
<?php
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");

    echo "aa";

    if(isset($_GET['emailid'])) {
        echo "aa";
        $emailid = $_GET['emailid'];
        $sql  = "SELECT emailid, phoneno, fname FROM registered WHERE emailid = '$emailid'";

        $query = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
        $resultfetch = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        $result = array();

        array_push($result, array(
                              "Emailid" => $resultfetch['emailid'],
                              "Phoneno" => $resultfetch['phoneno'],
                              "first name" => $resultfetch['fname']
        ));

        echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
        echo json_last_error_msg();
        mysqli_close($connect);
    }

?>
```

After running the above script the outer echo statement is been printed but inner echo isn't printed and the o/p in json is also unexpected `u`.The column name are also right

[you can check the images of database and o/p in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAUcs.png)

[o/p](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stvS1.png)

Comment: unexpected 'a' or 'u'? post the response

Comment: it shows unexpected 'a' but when i place cursor on the cross mark it popups unexpected 'u'

Comment: what url you are using ?

Comment: it most likely is a problem with your table structure, are you sure the structure of the table is good? post the api(url link) for that webservice api

Comment: is your api response of type json?

Comment: i'm running it on localhost but haven't specified encoding type to json

Comment: i have uploaded the image as  link in o/p you can check it @ScottS

Comment: How could you pass emailid in your header?

Comment: try moving this line:  $emailid = $_GET['emailid']; above if and change this line "if(isset($_GET['emailid']))" to if(isset($emailid))

Comment: change your url to: "http://localhost/1/b1.php?emailid=aa" or replace aa for the id you want to get info from.

Comment: Moving the line above will generate a notice undefined index and have also executed the link error is same @ScottS

Comment: It is an s/w that allows you to check your php files and other related stuff @Nawin

Comment: Your sentence doesn't make any sense.  Please use proper english. "Moving the line above will generate a notice undefined index and have also executed the link error is same"?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this and change your method get to post, pass your email in body

```
if(isset($_POST['emailid'])) {
        echo "aa";
        $emailid = $_POST['emailid'];
        $sql  = "SELECT emailid, phoneno, fname FROM registered WHERE emailid = '$emailid'";

        $query = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
        $resultfetch = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        $result = array();

        array_push($result, array(
                              "Emailid" => $resultfetch['emailid'],
                              "Phoneno" => $resultfetch['phoneno'],
                              "first name" => $resultfetch['fname']
        ));

        echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
        echo json_last_error_msg();
        mysqli_close($connect);
    }
```

Comment: Body option is been disabled for get method

Comment: Yes you should change in your left side dropdown for post method... If you want to in Get method means you should pass your value in Url only Not in header

Comment: Ohh sorry man haven't read your code throughly you replaced GET with post and yes after changing it provides the desired o/p thanx budyyy :)

Comment: But i want to get data from user so its appropriate to use POST ??

Comment: Did you get your result?

Comment: yup i have also  done that answered to you answer :)